# Odoo 9 : How to pass parameters to query (display result in tree view) via wizard

Tags: odoo, psql, odoo-9, qweb

I have this wizard where I select date :

```
<record id="wizard_forecast_invoice_date_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">wizard.forecast.invoice.date.form</field>
            <field name="model">custom_accounting.wizard_forecast_due_collection</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Date for Forecast Due Collection">
                    <separator string="Date for Forecast Due Collection"/>
                    <label string="This will list all open customer invoices that are on or before the Due Date selected"/>
                    <group>
                        <field name="before_date"/>                        
                    </group>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="forecast_due_collection" string="Okay" type="object" class="btn-primary" context="{'before_date': before_date}"/>
                        <button special="cancel" string="Cancel" class="btn-default"/>
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Where I want send this date value to new class like this :

```
class WizardForecastDueCollection(models.TransientModel):
    _name='custom_accounting.wizard_forecast_due_collection'
    before_date = fields.Date(string='Before Date', required=True, default=fields.Date.context_today)

    @api.multi
    def forecast_due_collection(self):
        ac = self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_id('custom_accounting.view_forecast_invoice_date_report_pivot')
        return {
            'name': 'ForecastInvoiceDateReport',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'res_model': 'custom_accounting.forecast_invoice_date_report',
            'view_id': ac,
            'context': {'default_before_date': self.before_date},
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'pivot',
            'domain': [('date_invoice', '<=', self.before_date)]
        }
```

And here's the class which should receive the value to execute the query :

```
class ForecastInvoiceDateReport(models.Model):
    _name = "custom_accounting.forecast_invoice_date_report"
    _description = "Forecast Invoices Date Report"

    date_maturity = fields.Date(string='Due Date', readonly=True)
    date_invoice = fields.Date(string='Invoice Date', readonly=True)
    before_date = fields.Date(store=False, default=lambda s: fields.Date.context_today(s))
    # account_id = fields.Many2one('account.account', string='Account', readonly=True, domain=[('deprecated', '=', False)])
    country = fields.Char('Country', readonly=True)
    sales_person_name = fields.Char('Sales Person', readonly=True)
    partner_name = fields.Char('Customer', readonly=True)
    state = fields.Char('State', readonly=True)
    city = fields.Char('City', readonly=True)
    debit = fields.Float("Debit", readonly=True)
    credit = fields.Float("Credit", readonly=True)
    amount_residual = fields.Float("Balance", digits_compute=dp.get_precision('accounting_financial_report_dp'),
                                   readonly=True)

    duration = fields.Char('Duration', readonly=True)
    invoice_number = fields.Char('Invoice Number', readonly=True)

    _auto = False
    _rec_name = 'date_maturity'
    _depends = {
        'account.move': ['id', 'name'],
        'account.move.line': ['move_id', 'date_maturity'],
        'res.currency.rate': ['currency_id', 'name'],
        'res.partner': ['country_id', 'state_id', 'city'],
        'account.invoice': ['date_invoice'],
    }

    def _select(self):

        select_str = """
          SELECT 
                row_number() OVER () as id, duration, date_invoice, date_maturity, 
                country,state,city, sales_person_name, concat(partner_name,'(', Payment_Term, ')') partner_name ,
                balance,amount_residual, debit,credit,invoice_number
          From 
          (
                SELECT 
                    case 
                      when "account_move_line".date_maturity is null Then 'No Date'
                      when (%s-ai.date_invoice) <30 then 'b#  0-30 days'
                      else 'Older'
                    END as duration, ai.date_invoice as date_invoice, "account_move_line".date_maturity as date_maturity,
                    res_country.name as country,res_country_state.name as state,res_partner.city as city,
                    new_rp.name as "sales_person_name", res_partner.name as "partner_name", res_partner.id as "partner_id1",          
                   COALESCE(SUM("account_move_line".balance), 0) AS balance, 
                   COALESCE(SUM("account_move_line".amount_residual), 0) AS amount_residual, 
                   COALESCE(SUM("account_move_line".debit), 0) AS debit, 
                   COALESCE(SUM("account_move_line".credit), 0) AS credit,
                   "account_move_line__move_id".name AS invoice_number
                   FROM "account_move" as "account_move_line__move_id","account_move_line" 
                   LEFT JOIN res_partner on "account_move_line".partner_id = res_partner.id 
                   LEFT JOIN res_country on res_partner.country_id = res_country.id 
                   LEFT JOIN res_country_state on res_partner.state_id = res_country_state.id 
                   LEFT JOIN res_users on res_partner.user_id = res_users.id 
                   LEFT JOIN res_partner as new_rp on res_users.partner_id = new_rp.id 
                   INNER JOIN account_account as aa on "account_move_line"."account_id"=aa.id
                   INNER JOIN account_invoice as ai on "account_move_line"."invoice_id"=ai.id
                 INNER JOIN account_account_type as aat on aat.id = aa.user_type_id 
                   WHERE ("account_move_line"."move_id"="account_move_line__move_id"."id") 
                   AND ((((  
                   (aat.type = 'receivable') and account_move_line__move_id.state='posted' and 
                     ("account_move_line"."reconciled" IS NULL or "account_move_line"."reconciled" = false ))  
                   )  AND  ("account_move_line__move_id"."state" = 'posted'))
                   ) GROUP BY 
                    case
                      when "account_move_line".date_maturity is null Then 'No Date'
                      when (%s-ai.date_invoice) <30 then 'b#  0-30 days'
                      else 'Older'
                    END
                    , new_rp.name , res_partner.name, res_country.name,res_country_state.name,res_partner.city,res_users.login,
                    "account_move_line".date_maturity,"account_move_line__move_id".name,ai.date_invoice,res_partner.id
                                order by 3
          ) as q1
          left join
          (
              SELECT Substr(res_id,13) partner_id2,Substr(value_reference,22) Payment_Term_Id,pt.name Payment_Term
              FROM public.ir_property ir join account_payment_term pt on pt.id = cast(Substr(value_reference,22) as integer)
              where ir.name ='property_payment_term_id'
          ) as q2 on q1.partner_id1 = cast(q2.partner_id2 as integer)

           """ %(self.before_date, self.before_date)
        return select_str

    _table = 'custom_forecast_invoices_date_view'

    def init(self, cr):
        # self._table = account_invoice_report
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, self._table)
        cr.execute("""CREATE or REPLACE VIEW %s as (
                    WITH currency_rate AS (%s)
                    %s
                )""" % (
            self._table, self.pool['res.currency']._select_companies_rates(),
            self._select()))
```

It works fine if I replace the field **before_date** by **current_date** in sql query, But if I set parameters instead, I can't get the expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it,
Just run the query in the first class of wizard, that's all :)

Comment: Can you share the solution, please?